# Keystore file 'C:\...\android\app\<keystore.jks>' not found for signing config 'release'

Tags: flutter, apk, keystore

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

> Keystore file 'C:\Users\Sam\StudioProjects\map_edinburgh_guide_airbnb\android\app<keystore.jks>' not found for signing config 'release'.

How torturous is this whole process?!

So I've generated a keystore, twice, once I put it on this path:
`C:\Users\Sam\StudioProjects\keystore`

But AS seemed to want it elsewhere, so I generated the keystore again, to the project directory, as above, modifying my key.properties file to:

```
keyAlias=key0
storeFile=<keystore.jks>
```

You can see I've omitted the path from `storeFile`, but if I don't AS seems to use the same path twice & throws this:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'C:\Users\Sam\StudioProjects\map_edinburgh_guide_airbnb\android\app\<C:\Users\Sam\StudioProjects\map_edinburgh_guide_airbnb\android\app\keystore.jks>' not found for signing config 'release'.
```

Bonkers!

OMG this is killing me, please help.

Comment: Have you put your `keystore` file in the `android\app\` folder of your project ?

Comment: Yes I have, on the second attempt.  The problem as given.  I wondered if I'm not meant to wrap things in <> brackets in the properties file, but when I remove them, still problems.

Comment: key.properties is simply in the parent android/ directory

Comment: You can use relative path. In the Key.properties you can use `app\key.jks`

Comment: Gives this error:
> Keystore file ```'C:\Users\Sam\StudioProjects\map_edinburgh_guide_airbnb\android\app\<app\keystore.jks>' not found for signing config 'release'.```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, the angle brackets provided in the docs should be REMOVED from all field, storePassword, keyPassowrd, alias, & storeFile

THANK THE LORD!

Comment: The angle brackets are placeholders for the actual path name

Answer (score 0):

storeFile=C:/Users/yassa/upload-keystore.jks

\ to / and the error is gone

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).